# How to dynamically display images in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and wanted to display images inside my loop. I am successfully able to display it outside loop but can't display it within loop. I want to implement these 2 code  lines to bottom code besides  content.append(nn2[2] + "\n").Hope you guys understand:

```
ImageView i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((new URL ("httpS://graph.facebook.com/497305810301446/picture?type=large")).openConnection().getInputStream());
                            i2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        //layout4.addView(i2);
```

Below is the loop where I wanted to display images:

```
Url=new URL( "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abc/users/get_fb.json?term="+searchValue);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    //     InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    Log.d("hello","world");
                    //InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader();
                    SetServerString = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    Log.d("hello",SetServerString);

                    String[] nn=SetServerString.split("name");
                    String nn2[];
                    String nn3,nn4;

                    //  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(SetServerString);
                    content.setText("");

                    for(int a=0;a<nn.length;a++){

                            // nn2=nn[a].split(",");
                            //  nn3=nn2[0].replaceAll("\":\"", "");
                            nn4 = nn[a].replaceAll("[id\\:\\}\\{\\[\\]\"]", "");

                            nn2 = nn4.split(",");
                            // nn3=nn2[1].replaceAll("[\\:\\}\\{\\[\\]\"]","");
                            //  content.append(nn2.length+" \n ");
                           int p=1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < nn2.length && nn2.length > 1; i++) {
                                if(p==1) {
                                content.append(nn2[0] + "\n");
                                if (nn2.length > 2) {

                                    content.append(nn2[2] + "\n");
                                } else {
                                    content.append(nn2[1] + "\n");
                                }
                                p = 0;
                            }
                            }
```

Comment: what do you mean by inside a loop?

Comment: What is the error exactly ? you can paste your logcat, if any error or exception happens. anyway, the real problem is a little bit vague

Comment: Your title says "generate", your text says "display" - which is it?

Comment: my text is displayed at :content.append(nn2[2] + "\n"); I want to display images beside it inside loop

Comment: There is no error in logcat @FarhadFaghihi

Comment: I don't want to use (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2) through xml as I have random many images through url request in my below code. I haven't added images to below code.Hope u guys got it

Comment: @BasimKhan can you explain more ?

Comment: @Moudiz plz read top description again carefully

Comment: what are the errors if you get if you add them below nn2= nn4.... ? @BasimKhan

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. It handles displaying, downloading and caching images very easily.

With Picasso, you can simply type:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

and that's all for loading single image.

If you want to load many images, it's better to use e.g. `ListView` and create specific adapter. After that, you can use Picasso inside your adapter.

Comment: i would appreciate if you could provide me simple example of using images through picasso in listview or any link. Thanks anyway @piotr.wittchen

Answer (score 0):

you can use any picasso or universal-image-loader

add universal-image-loader jar (google and download)

and use the method

```
/**Load initially other pics**/
public void loadPic(String url)
{

    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageview, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.errorimg);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimg);
        }
    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {

        }
    });
}
```